# If $f(n) + (n+1)^2 = f(n+1)$ then what is $f\phantom{|}$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, functional-equations

Suppose that $$f(n) + (n+1)^2 = f(n+1),$$

1. How could I find the original (or family of) function(s) that satisfies this property?
2. What is the branch of mathematics that deals with equations like this?

Comment: You're trying to solve a *functional equation*.

Comment: Assuming you meant $f(n)$ rather than $f(x)$ in your equation, then this is simply a case of a linear recurrence relation (with constant coefficients!), or definition by recursion. There is a branch of mathematics called recursive function theory but it is almost surely not what you're interested in. I suspect you want to know about solutions to more complicated *functional equations* like $f(f(x)) = x$, but I don't think this is a well-understood topic in mathematics yet.

Comment: With the edit: you now have a *difference equation*, or as Henry says, a recurrence/recursion relation.

Comment: 1. You're looking for an antidifference of a hypergeometric, so Gosper's algorithm will give you the solution.

Answer (score 5):

That is a [recurrence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation).  There will be a family of solutions, depending on the starting point.  For example, starting with $f(0)=0$, it will simply be the sum of squares, which is $f(n)=n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$.  If you started from $f(0)=1$ it would be $(n+2)(2n^2-n+3)/6$.

There are various ways of solving it. One is spot that since the first difference $f(n+1)-f(n) = n^2+2n+1$ is a quadratic polynomial, $f(n)$ will be a cubic polynomial, so you can use the early values to find the coefficients.

Another would be to use generating functions, for example described in [generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html).

And there are more, such as methods associated with [functional equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_equation).

Comment: +1: Of course the general solution for arbitrary $f(0)=c$ is [not too difficult](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28n%2B1%29-f%28n%29%3D%28n%2B1%29*%28n%2B1%29).

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=n+1$ ,

Then $f(x)=f(x-1)+x^2$

In fact this belongs to a functional equation of the form http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/fe/fe1108.pdf.

The general solution of this functional equation is $f(x)=\Theta(x)+f_p(x)$ , where $\Theta(x)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with unit period

Luckily we can find $f_p(x)$ by method of undetermined coefficients:

Let $f_p(x)=Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx$ ,

Then $f_p(x-1)=A(x-1)^3+B(x-1)^2+C(x-1)=Ax^3-3Ax^2+3Ax-A+Bx^2-2Bx+B+Cx-C=Ax^3+(B-3A)x^2+(3A-2B+C)x-A+B-C$

$\therefore Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx-(Ax^3+(B-3A)x^2+(3A-2B+C)x-A+B-C)\equiv x^2$

$3Ax^2+(2B-3A)x+A-B+C\equiv x^2$

$\therefore\begin{cases}3A=1\\2B-3A=0\\A-B+C=0\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}A=\dfrac{1}{3}\\B=\dfrac{1}{2}\\C=\dfrac{1}{6}\end{cases}$

$\therefore f(x)=\Theta(x)+\dfrac{x^3}{3}+\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x}{6}=\Theta(x)+\dfrac{2x^3+3x^2+x}{6}=\Theta(x)+\dfrac{x(x+1)(2x+1)}{6}$ , where $\Theta(x)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with unit period

$f(n)=\Theta(n)+\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ , where $\Theta(n)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with unit period